# django try exception statement causing IntegrityError:

Tags: django, django-views

We use paypal on our system to check whether a user has paid before and already has an account.
This morning I received a traceback that basically gave me an integrity error.

IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'user_1234_before' for key 2")

My statemtent looks as follows.

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(email=ipn_obj.payer_email)
except:
    user_slug = ("%s_%s_before") % (ipn_obj.first_name, ipn_obj.last_name)
    username = slugify(user_slug)
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, ipn_obj.payer_email, 'testpassword')
    user.first_name = ipn_obj.first_name
    user.last_name = ipn_obj.last_name
    user.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exception is caught with `except` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never, ever use a blank `except` statement. What's happening here is an excellent demonstration of why.

You've presumably used that try/except block to catch the `User.DoesNotExist` exception. However, your code is actually raising a completely different exception. Because you're swallowing it, it's impossible to know which one, but potentially `ipn_obj` isn't what you think it is and doesn't have a `payer_email` error, so you're getting `AttributeError`. Or, possibly, you're getting the `User.MultipleObjectReturned` exception.

Change your `except` to `except User.DoesNotExist`, and then debug your actual problem.

Comment: But the exception is raised by `User.objects.create_user(...)` and not by `User.objects.get(...)`

Comment: Yes, because he's getting into the `except` block when he shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two user with different `payer_mail` but same `first_name` and `last_name`: `username` (made up of first and last name) is the same for the two users. Probably `username` is a unique key on `User` and gives you the error.

Apart from catching the right exception (`User.DoesNotExist`), if you want to retain your code, I think you should 'uniquify' the `username` using the email field (which I suppose is unique):

```
user_slug = ("%s_%s_before") % (ipn_obj.first_name, ipn_obj.last_name)
```

with:

```
user_slug = ("%s_%s_%s_before") % (ipn_obj.first_name, ipn_obj.last_name, ipn_obj.payer_email)
```

or:

```
user_slug = ("%s_before") % (ipn_obj.payer_email)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is actually being raised by the creation (ie INSERT statement) of a user with an already took username.
You shall check for its existence before doing this insertion .